# How to determine if a region's view and all its nested regions/views have finished loading

Tags: c#, silverlight, prism

I'm integrating a Prism project with Silverlight's nav framework. Part of the task is to update the URL when an appropriate change happens in the app.

One area which I'm stuck with is how to determine if a region has finished 'loading' and all the appropriate view models have been instantiated.

I'm using view discovery and region.Activate to trigger the region. This method appears to return before all the view models have been created.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: What about Loaded event that exist in a UserControl?

Comment: There is some sort of behind the scenes delay mechanism which doesn't load the child regions, so Loaded didn't work for me. I was able to hack together something with help from a colleague (using the static method RegionManager.UpdateRegions()) -- wondering if there is a better solution.